# Is it possible to compile c program on Mac which is compilable on Windows?

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote a c program on windows. It can compile properly on this OS. It uses `windows.h` library.
Can I compile it by **GCC** compilers on Mac? Or I must to change the code?
I heard c is portable; therefore it should can run on Mac. Yes?

Comment: `Windows.h` is not a standard header file, it is a OS specific header file, so the library associated with this header is not portable.

Comment: You should be able to, as long as you stick to the appropriate standard  pedantically. This can rather be tedious - starting with strictly sticking to a C standard understood by all compilers you use, figure out the correct command line arguments to tell the compiler to actually use that precise standard, then restrict yourself to e.g. a subset of POSIX both Windows and the Mac understand... As machine_1 stated, I would be rather surprised if `windows.h` was part of any standard a Mac OS (no matter which one)  will implement. My guess would be that you have to port your program.

Comment: And if you port your program (and its not a 3 liner), then severly consider using libraries - there are a lot of libraries out there that aim at keeping your programs portable. I do not know about Macs, but e.g. gtk would be an example for such kind of library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either change the code or install something on your system to provide a substitute for `<windows.h>`, because it is not a standard header on macOS with Apple’s developer tools.

Assuming you do not install some substitute, if any exist, then you must remove `#include <windows.h>`. Whether you must change any other code, and how much, depends on what facilities you have used from `<windows.h>` and cannot be answered without knowing more about your code.

C is portable. The C standard defines a core subset of the language called *strictly conforming*. Strictly conforming code is portable to all C implementations. Most C programs include code outside that subset. It is portable to some extent, but there are many qualifications to that, many implementation dependencies, and many subtleties. Commonly, any complicated program requires changes in order to run on a new platform unless it was carefully designed for portability.